# Brand New 2 Stories House vibrates when it's windy

Tags: wind

I had a house built a year ago and ever since I've moved in, when it's really windy outside the second floor of the house vibrates. At night I can feel the bed move. It's making me very nervous and I'm not sure what should I do. Just to mention that on the back side of the house there is an open field so when the wind is strong it really hits the house hard.

Please let me know your recommendations.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Complain to your builder (try to have them visit on a windy day) and ask what they can or will do about it.

The next step is probably:

Plant trees to provide a windbreak. Without knowing where you are, a general suggestion would be something fast-growing but not, perhaps, the tree you'd love to have mixed with trees that grow slower and have more desirable properties - hybrid poplars being a prime example of the first type - they grow fast, and you probably won't mind cutting them down when the other trees grow more and fill in - but they do grow fast.

[image]

If you have a high budget I suppose you could try building a fence high enough to impact the wind on the second story, but that's an expensive proposition. Fencing for windbreak should be about 25-50% open, not solid; a solid fence diverts it up, and the air currents downwind can be worse than without a fence - a partially-open fence (or tree branches) slows it down more effectively.

[Farm-oriented but fairly understandable wind mitigation info from Purdue.](https://www.extension.purdue.edu/extmedia/NCR/NCR-191.html)

[An example of a large commercial wind fence.](http://linearcomposites.net/?pageid=parafence.xml)